# Dirac structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $M$  is $m$-dimensional smooth manifold and $\pi: TM\oplus T^{*}M \longrightarrow M $ is a smooth vector bundle. Suppose $L$ is the Dirac structure i.e. it is a subbundle of $(TM \oplus T^{*}M,π)$ which isotropic with natural pairing in $TM\oplus T^{*}M $ and of maximal rank $m$ and involutive with Courant bracket. For any $(x \in M)$ we denote  $L_{x} $ a fiber of subbundle $L$ which it call linear Dirac structure. The space of all subspace $L_{x}$ which denote by $Dir (L_{x}) $ diffeomorphic the manifold with two connected component.

1. How can regard a subbundle $L$ as a family of subspaces of linear Dirac structure, varying smoothly with x? $(x \in M)$
2. How can you say for any $(x \in M)$, the connected components of $ Dir(L_{x}) $ have a direct relation of connected components of $M$?